# In Unicode environment, How can I convert from CString to String?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

```
CString strfile = _T("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\스캔\\LowerScanFile.ply"); //Korean
CString strfile = _T("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\ScanFile_11_12\\LowerScanFile.ply"); //English
CString strfile = _T("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\歯科医療機器\\LowerScanFile.ply"); //Chinese
CString strfile = _T("C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\München\\LowerScanFile.ply"); //German

wchar_t *wchar_str;
    char *char_str;
    int char_str_len;

    wchar_str = strfile.GetBuffer(strfile.GetLength());

    char_str_len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wchar_str, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char_str = new char[char_str_len];

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wchar_str, -1, char_str, char_str_len, 0, 0);
```

[Result]

char_str = 0x0000027b188b8420 "C:\Users\A\Desktop\스캔\LowerScanFile.ply"

char_str = 0x0000027e30dd8030 "C:\Users\A\Desktop\ScanFile_11_12\LowerScanFile.ply"

char_str = 0x000001c91d7781b0 "C:\Users\A\Desktop\Munchen\LowerScanFile.ply"

char_str = 0x000001dc30839530 "C:\Users\A\Desktop\?科?療機器\LowerScanFile.ply"

'char_str' value converted normally only in Korean and English.

I'd like to all languages ​convert CString to String normally.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). Once that is fixed, you'll need to brush up your MFC. Every `CString` needs to be replaced by `CStringW`, every `_T` by `L`, and nearly every call to `GetBuffer()` needs to be `GetString()`. Besides, `CP_ACP` is virtually always wrong.

Comment: Stop using TCHAR and "T" string macros.

Comment: Pass CP_UTF8 to WideCharToMultiByte instead of CP_ACP.  With that being said, the conversion will be correct, but depending on how you inspect it in the debugger, render in on the screen, or print to the console the results might look garbled. What are you really trying to do by converting UTF-16 into an 8-bit encoding?

Answer (score 2):

You've titled the question `String`, but there's no such class. The actual code shows `char*`, so I presume you mean an array of plain `char` characters.

In Visual C++, `char` is 8 bit. The interpretation of these bits varies. Pretty much every API agrees that `char` is a superset of ASCII, but beyond that it's pretty much unspecified. You're writing that you're in a "Unicode environment", yet you use `CP_ACP` instead of `CP_UTF8`. UTF-8 is *the* standard way to store unicode characters in `char[]`. However, because there are more than 256 Unicode characters, you'll need more than one `char` per Unicode code point.

(This also holds for `wchar_t` on Visual C++. It's 16 bits, but Unicode requires 20 bits per code point).

Comment: Assuming no normalization transformation, a UTF-8 encoded string will need no more than twice the number of code units as the corresponding UTF-16 encoded string.

Comment: @IInspectable Unicode codepoints in the range U+0800..U+FFFF (not counting the reserved surrogate codepoints U+D800..U+DFFF) will use 3x as many UTF-8 codeunits as UTF-16 codeunits, not 2x as you claim. Only codepoints in the ranges of U+0080..U+07FF and U+10000..U+10FFFF use 2x as many UTF-8 codeunits as UTF-16 codeunits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, I had this backward. A UTF-16 encoded string will need no more than twice the number of code units as the corresponding UTF-8 encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: **Strings are either Unicode<sup>1</sup> or garbage.**

The question doesn't make it clear what the *goal* is, so I'm going to have to guess. If the goal is to trash data by transforming it from a well-defined encoding (UTF-16LE) into one that isn't self-sufficient<sup>2</sup>, then that is a lot easier to do:

```cpp
CStringW wide_str = L"歯科医療機器"; // Chinese
// Have MFC trash the data for us
CStringA acp_str = wide_str;
// Done; request a pointer if needed
char const* c_str = acp_str.GetString();
```

`CStringT`'s [conversion constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt) internally calls [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte), passing `CP_ACP` as the desired code page identifier. When the default Windows ANSI code page cannot represent all characters, data has become irrecoverably corrupted.

Given how easy it was to do that, it would be crazy to let that go unnoticed. Instead, we want the compiler to fail hard if it catches us trying to corrupt data. Thankfully, this is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#remarks-8):

> Define the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` macro to turn off implicit string conversion between ANSI and Unicode strings. The macro excludes from compilation constructors that support conversion.

With the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` macro defined, the code above will no longer compile.

---

Now that we have established that code page encoding cannot persist string information, what are the alternatives?

The obvious one up front: Keep everything UTF-16LE and never convert. This matches Windows' internal encoding, and there is never any ambiguity about what encoding any given wide-character string uses. It is the preferred option.

If, on the other hand, you need to interface with foreign code that only provides a narrow-character interface, you will have to convert. The only tractable option here is to use UTF-8. You can either manually do the conversion using `WideCharToMultiByte()` with the `CP_UTF8` code page or use the ATL/MFC string conversion utilities that allow you to specify an explicit code page (such as [`CW2AEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cw2aex-class)).

If the foreign code only provides a narrow-character interface but doesn't understand UTF-8, then that implementation is broken. You will need to approach the vendor and have them fix the code. This is not something that can be fixed (or even just worked around) by client code.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)*

<sup>2</sup> *[Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers): "ANSI code pages can be different on different computers, or can be changed for a single computer, leading to data corruption."*